# How to get the record of Wifi networks connected using C#? I tried to extract from registry but it Gives null exception

Tags: c#

```
using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged"))
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string sk in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(sk))
            {    
                listBoxCard.Items.Add(sk1.GetValue("Description"));        
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Well what diagnosis have you performed? Have you stepped through it with a debugger? Is `sk` non-null? Is `sk1` non-null? Is `listBoxCard` non-null?

Comment: Note that when I try that, I get a SecurityException on the very first line.

Comment: Open source project http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/

Comment: I just want to get the WIFI router that i have connected with.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works fine for me in listing the network interfaces I have on my computer.

However, I needed to elevate the privileges to access the information and did that by adding an **Application Manifest File** and in it changing the **requestedExecutionLevel** to **requireAdministrator**.

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```